# Read a line from a file

Tags: guile

I'm trying to figure out how to read a line from a file with guile scheme.

When I ask it to "read port" or "read-char port", it successfully reads.

```
guile -c '(let ((port (open-input-file "foo.txt"))) (display (read port)) (newline) (close-port port))'
```

But, when I ask it to read-line, it fails.

```
guile -c '(let ((port (open-input-file "foo.txt"))) (display (read-line port)) (newline) (close-port port))'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am currently in the directory where foo.txt is located.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code fails with the message `ERROR: Unbound variable: read-line`, meaning that there is no definition for `readline`.

The function `read-line` has to be loaded using the form `(use-modules (ice-9 rdelim))` before you can use it. (https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Input-and-Output.html)

This will then work:

```
guile -c '(use-modules (ice-9 rdelim)) (let ((port (open-input-file "foo.txt"))) 
(display (read-line port)) (newline) (close-port port))'
```